# Prove that there exists a point $x_0∈ [a,b]$, where $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(x_0)>0$, then $∫^a_bf(x)dx>0$

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

I have that the function $f(x)$ is integrable and $f(x)>0$ in the interval $[a,b]$ I need to prove that there exists a point $x_0 ∈[a,b]$, where $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(x_0)>0$, then $∫^a_bf(x)dx>0$

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You have a history of posting problems here without your own contributions or showing any of your own understanding.

Comment: @user296602 I don't know how to start so that's why I wrote any ideas to help me start somehow.

Comment: Have you tried nothing at all? Where did you encounter this problem? What background results do you know? Can you at least draw a picture and interpret an integral in terms of an area? This is not a do-my-homework site.

Comment: @user296602 I've proven that If f(x)>0 and integrable in [a,b] then $∫^a_bf(x)dx>0$ but in this one I don't get why I have to prove it for a point in [a,b]

Comment: @Karolina I guess you want to write $\int_a^b$ instead of $\int_b^a$. However the question is far to be clear.

Comment: Are you sure you have the phrasing of question correct? ... if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x) dx > 0$ then there exist a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) > 0$ by the mean value theorem.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>0$ then there is a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<f(x_0)/2$ when $|x-x_0|<\delta$. In particular, $f(x_0)/2<f(x)$ for $|x-x_0|<\min(\delta,|x_0-a|,|x_0,b|)=M$. Therefore $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\geq\int_{x_0-M}^{x_0+M}f(x)>\int_{x_0-M}^{x_0+M}f(x_0)/2>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little messy in terms of its statements and phrasing, so I'll demonstrate two separate and possible cases :

**First case :**

If you have the facts : $$f(x) \space\text{continuous and integrable on} \space [a,b] \space \text{and} \space f(x_0) > 0 \space \text{for} \space x_0 \in [a,b]$$

then you're missing out on one fact, that $b-a >0$.

To see that, take the function :

$$g(t) = \int_a^t f(x)dx$$

The function $f(x)$ is continuous which means that $g(x)$ will be continuous in such an interval and of course differentiable too. Taking the interval $[a,b]$ which is the one that is nicely set and defined for $f(x)$ via the exercise, the *Mean Value Theorem* can be applied for $x_0 \in \mathbb (a,b)$ :

$$g'(x_0)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a} = \frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx-\int_a^af(x)dx}{b-a} = \frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{b-a}$$

$$ \Rightarrow $$

$$\bigg[\int_a^tf(x)dx\bigg]'_{t=x_0} = \frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{b-a} \Rightarrow f(x_0) = \frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{b-a} \Leftrightarrow \int_a^bf(x)dx=f(x_0)(b-a)$$

Now, if $f(x_0)>0$ from the facts given. If $b-a>0$, then we have proved that :

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx>0$$

**Second case :**

If you have the facts : $$f(x) \space\text{continuous and integrable on} \space [a,b] \space \text{and} \space \int_a^b f(x) > 0$$

then one can prove by taking the same function as above :

$$g(t) = \int_a^t f(x)dx$$

and following a similar path by applying the *Mean Value Theorem*, that there exists $x_0 \in [a,b] : f(x_0) > 0$.

**Note :** ("Shout out" to @DougM as he also mentioned the *Mean Value Theorem* approach in the comments as I was writing the answer)

Comment: I feel ridiculous asking this, but I have a compulsive need to clarify— $$\left[\int_a^tf(x)\,dx\right]^\prime_{t=x_0} = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_a^tf(x)\,dx\right)\right|_{t=x_0}\quad ?$$

Comment: You can have also the case in which $f$ is known to be continuous only at $x_0$. A reason why negative 'shout outs' to the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @orole From the exercise sayings it looks like $f$ is continuous. There's no reason for "negative" shout outs when you're presenting a case work/help to a question that's not stated at strict as it should be. If you want to go as far as that to give "negative" shout outs to a method used, it's not even stated what kind of function $f$ is (real, complex, imaginary, integer - and - and - and). Provide cases for every single (infinite) possibilities then (impossible).

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I had a small typo naming $g(x)$ instead of $g(t)$ which would of course be wrong, so thanks for the comment since I found the typo by that ! Truly though, if $g(t)$ is stated as mentioned, then its derivative $g'(t)$ follows as this. I denoted the use of the notation $'$ as the derivative with respect to $t$, since $g(t)$ is a function of the unrestricted variable $t$.

Comment: The question would only need 'if' between 'that' and 'there' to make sense and not be answered by any of those cases. Moreover, it is not a good thing when the reasons why something is true get hidden behind the name of a theorem.